# MongoDb query for returning all elements whose arrays at least one element from query array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say I have a document structured as such:

```
{ "_id": 1, nums: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] },
{ "_id": 2, nums: [2, 4, 6, 8] },
{ "_id": 3, nums: [1, 3, 5, 7] },
```

What query should I use if I want all elements that have at least one of the following numbers in their `nums` property: [6, 7, 8]?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using `$in`operator:

```js
db.collection.find({
  nums: {
    $in: [
      6,
      7,
      8
    ]
  }
})
```